# Encrypting a Binary (.bin) file using the Crypto module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, encoding, cryptography

I have a 4MB binary (.bin) file on a server that I need to encrypt (preferably generating a plaintext file) and decrypt the encrypted file to regenerate the original bin file later on. Firstly, I create the cipher and decipher objects.

```
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv); //key, iv have been initialized before
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv); //same key and iv
```

After that, I tried the following two methods to encrypt/decrypt the file:-

1. Encrypting and Decrypting the `utf-8` encoding of the binary data

```
const response = await fetch(URL) //size of response.blob() is 4194304 bytes = 4MB
const text = await response.text(); //size of text is 8206273 bytes

let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf-8', 'hex');
encrypted += cipher.final('hex'); //size of encrypted is 16412576 bytes
// Save the encrypted string as 'encrypted.txt' plaintext file

let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'hex', 'utf-8'); 
decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');//size of decrypted is 8206273 bytes
// decrypted and text have the same size and seem identical in their content
```

How do I regenerate the exact same .bin file from `decrypted`?

2. Using a `TypedArray` representation of the `Response`'s `ArrayBuffer`

```
const response = await fetch(URL)
const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer(); //size of arrayBuffer is 4194304 bytes = 4MB
const typedArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer); //size of typedArray is 4194304 bytes = 4MB

let encrypted = cipher.update(typedArray) //ERROR - "list" argument must be an Array of Buffers
```

Going through Crypto's [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_update_data_inputencoding_outputencoding), not passing the input and output encoding arguments to `cipher.update()` results in the function expecting a `Buffer`/`TypedArray` and outputs a `Buffer` as well.

The error is shown in detail here:

```
TypeError: "list" argument must be an Array of Buffers
    at Function.concat (index.js:420)
    at Splitter.push../node_modules/browserify-aes/encrypter.js.Splitter.add (encrypter.js:73)
    at Cipher.push../node_modules/browserify-aes/encrypter.js.Cipher._update (encrypter.js:29)
    at Cipher.push../node_modules/cipher-base/index.js.CipherBase.update (index.js:35)
    at _callee$ (index.js:50)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:282)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:116)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:32
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:21
    at _ED (index.js:24)
    at ED (index.js:24)
    at _callee2$ (index.js:103)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:282)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:116)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
```

I am currently stuck at this error. I tried other variations like passing a Buffer itself but without much success.

Any suggestions or help regarding how to proceed with either of the methods would be highly appreciated.

I would love to know if other better methods exist for this particular task.

PS: The .bin file is `TF.js`'s way of storing model weights. A sample can be found [here](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/ssd_mobilenet_v2/1/default/1?tfjs-format=compressed) in TF-Hub's [SSD model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/ssd_mobilenet_v2/1/default/1).

Comment: If it's a _binary_ file, `reponse.text()` will corrupt the data, since an Utf8 encoding is performed. This is probably why decryption fails. Try `Response.arrayBuffer()`, which will give you an `ArrayBuffer` that can be imported directly into a NodeJS `Buffer`, s. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response). Also, the `final()`-calls seem to be missing (the results of `update()` and `final()` calls are to be concatenated, s. [here, 3rd example](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher)).

Comment: @user9014097 Hey, yeah, I forgot to add the final calls() in my question. I have edited it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Regarding the arrayBuffer() suggestion, as you can see in the second method, I am already using it to create a TypedArray which if I know correctly, are similar to Buffers or rather, Buffer instances are TypedArray instances as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @user9014097. Dunno, why I even used TypedBuffer. Simply passing a Buffer instead of a TypedBuffer worked, and yeah, in the second method, I concatenated the decipher.final() to the decrypted Buffer and it worked.
Thanks a lot for the help.